# How to get solidity custom errors on dApp?

Tags: solidity, javascript, dapps, custom-errors

I would like to get the custom error code from my dApp, however, I can't get it when the smart contract is using revert. However, I can get the error reason when the solidity contract use required.

Ex. If the smart contract has `revert TransactionAlreadyExecuted`, from the Javascript I only get that the transaction was reverted without any reason.

However, when I use `require(!_usedNonce[nonce], "Transaction already executed");` I gent the reason (string) without issues.

Is there any special way to get the reason errors for custom errors (revert) from Javascript?

JIC, solidity version is 0.8.13